# How to get text which is between two containers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to parse some text, that is in between two containers. I cannot change the structure of the HTML, it is how it is. Following is the markup:

```
<span class="location" title="Donetsk, Donetskaya, Ukraine"><img data-src="/media/images/4.0/flags/ua.gif" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;" src="/media/images/4.0/flags/ua.gif">&nbsp;&nbsp;Ukraine</span>

                                 | 
                Rate: $35
                             | 
            IT & Programming

<div class="eol-level-small clickable" id="snap0" onmouseover="EOL.snapshot.tip('246969','10183','snap0')" onmouseout="EOL.snapshot.tipCancel()">16</div>
```

What i need to extract is the text:

```
                                 | 
                Rate: $35
                             | 
            IT & Programming
```

How can i do this with jQuery or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling) element of the element with class `location`

```
$('.location')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P9VLc/)

Answer (score -1):

Don't use text without Tag.It's unsafe to use nextSibling, because nextSibling has the different compatibility with IE and Moz.